# Replace in MongoDB With C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to actually replace a collection of Objects of type Game in my Collection "Games".

I want to replace these Objects with entirely new Objects. I have researched a bit on MongoDB and I see that 'UpdateMany' will replace Fields with new values but that's not exactly what I want. I wish to replace the entire Object.

For reference, this is my Game class:

```
public class Game
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Developer { get; set; }
  public int ProjectId { get; set; }

  public Game()
  {
   this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
 }
}
```

This is my method I am using to attempt a bulk Replace. I am passing in a ProjectId, so for all of the Game Objects that have a ProjectId = to the argument, replace the Object with a new Game Object.

```
 public static void ReplaceGame(int ProjectId, IMongoDatabase Database)
 {
   IMongoCollection<Game> gameCollection = Database.GetCollection<Game>("Game");
   List<Game> gameCollectionBeforeReplacement = gameCollection.Find(g => true).ToList();
   if (gameCollectionBeforeReplacement.Count == 0)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("No Games in Collection...");
     return;
    }

    var filter = Builders<Game>.Filter.Eq(g => g.ProjectId, ProjectId);
    foreach (Game game in gameCollection.AsQueryable())
        gameCollection.ReplaceOneASync(filter, new Game() { Title = "REPLACEMENT TITLE" });
    }
```

Not only does this take an excessive amount of time. I suspect it's because of the .AsQueryable() call but it also doesn't work. I am wondering how I can actually replace all instances picked up by my filter with new Game Objects.

Comment: You're not awaiting the async call there.

Comment: So would changing the method to public static async..and then in the foreach -> await gameCollection.ReplaceOneASync(filter, new Game() { Title = "REPLACEMENT TITLE" }; I am getting the exception:   After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id

Comment: Well, you can't change an immutable field. I'm not very familiar with Mongo, but rather than doing a bulk update can you delete them and reinsert?

Comment: That seems to be the way to go. But, is there a way to maintain the order when deleting? Sorting is kind of taxing, though.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following code:

```
public virtual ReplaceOneResult ReplaceOne(TDocument replacement, int projId)
{
    var filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq(x => x.ProjectId, projId);
    var result = Collection.ReplaceOne(filter, replacement, new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = false }, _cancellationToken);

    return result;
}
```

You will find that `ReplaceOneResult` has a property that tells you the matched count. This makes it possible for you to keep executing the ReplaceOne call until the matched count equals `0`. When this happens, you know all documents in your collection that had the corresponding project id have been replaced.

Example:

```
var result = ReplaceOne(new Game() { Title = "REPLACEMENT TITLE" }, 12);
while (result.MatchedCount > 0)
    result = ReplaceOne(new Game() { Title = "REPLACEMENT TITLE" }, 12);
```

This makes it so that you don't need the call to the database before you start replacing.

However, if you wish to insert the same values for every existing game, I would suggest you to do an UpdateMany operation. There you can use $set to specify all required values. The code above is simply not performant, with going to the database for every single replace call.